# TypeError: $(...) is null

Tags: javascript, salesforce, typeerror

My requirement is when I mouseover on helpText values will be displayed with hyperlinks in it, after clicking on hyperlink mouseout event should occur. For that I added a `click` event and then mouseout event. But getting error.

My code is:

```
<script>
   jQuery.noConflict();
    function doOnclick(){
        doMouseout();
    }
    function doMouseout(){
    alert('hi');
        $('Foo').hide();
    }
</script>

 <style>
    .helpLink {
      position:relative;
    }

    .video{
      display:none;
      width:160px;
      height:120px;
      background:#EEE;
      border:1px solid #CCC;

      position:absolute;

      z-index:10;
    }
  </style>


            <apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" onmouseover="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'block';">  <!-- title="help" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';" -->
                <apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="helpIcon" />
            </apex:outputLink>
            <apex:outputPanel id="Foo" styleClass="video" title="help" >
               <a  href="{!taburl}" target="_blank"  onclick="doOnclick();" >link</a>
               <a href="{!tabvideo}" target="_blank">Video</a>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Getting error:

> TypeError: $(...) is null

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict();` - so the `$` is some salesforce function? If so, please make that painfully obvious in the title.

Comment: Have you included jquery library? As f.e.: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Assuming `$` is simply `document.getElementById`, whatever `{!$Component.Foo}` is, it can't find that element inside the DOM and returns `null`.

Comment: I'm very poor in javascript.@pst $ is not a salesforce function.I have taken it as `var $=jQuery.noConflict();` but getting error.@Wouter in salesforce we will be inclding src as `<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"/>` & I included it

Comment: Have you tried simply `$('{!$Component.Foo}').show()`?

Comment: getting the same error.$() is null.but if I replace it as `jQuery('{!$Component.Foo}').hide();` error is not coming but block is not hiding.help me on this pls

Comment: @EagerinSf Well, of course. What else would `jQuery.noConflict()` do? Hence my original comment - please heed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used `jQuery.noConflict()` to return a different alias to use in order to avoid conflicts with other libraries that may be using `$`. By no means is it necessary to do this, but I find it helps avoid confusion.

That said, Salesforce does some unexpected things with element IDs on VF pages (but if you specify an ID in your VF markup, it will at least show up in the ID of the generated HTML *somewhere*), so I would recommend using a selector that grabs all elements with IDs *containing* what you're looking for, such as `jq$("[id*='Foo']")`.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}" />

<script >
    jq$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    function doOnclick(){
        doMouseout();
    }
    function doMouseout(){
        alert("hi");
        jq$("[id*='Foo']").hide();
    }
</script>

<style>
    .helpLink {
        position:relative;
    }
    .video{
        display:none;
        width:160px;
        height:120px;
        background:#EEE;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:10;
    }
</style>

<apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" onmouseover="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'block';">  <!-- title="help" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';" -->
    <apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="helpIcon" />
</apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputPanel id="Foo" styleClass="video" title="help" >
    <a  href="{!taburl}" target="_blank"  onclick="doOnclick();" >link</a>
    <a href="{!tabvideo}" target="_blank">Video</a>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: this works great.But here when I mouseout from the block (i.e., from style.display = 'block') which is displayed by mouseover on the image,then mouseout event should work.Apart from this, similutaneously when I click on the link, the block should hide & it works great